# Moran's I in panel data using contiguity matrix

Tags: spatial-statistics, regression, autocorrelation, moran-index, panel

I have some data in a panel format and want to run some spatial panel regression. In a cross-sectional framework, I would run a simple regression and test the spatial autocorrelation from the residuals (with Moran's I for instance). If the residuals are spatially correlated, that would suggest me to try a spatial regression.

How can I do it on with a panel data?

I've found just [one R package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GWPR.light/vignettes/introduction_of_GWPR.html) that performs this, but it seems weird to me as it's not possible to choose the spatial weights matrix. From what I get we can just use a contiguity one.

Is this the right way to test for spatial correlation on the residuals of a panel estimation? Is there any other package (R or another language) to do this?